# Is it possible to simplify this binomial expression?

Tags: convergence-divergence, integers, negative-binomial

There is binomial expression(s) written as
$$\sum_{n>0}\frac{(-3n+2k-3)n!^2}{2(2n+1)(k-1)!^2(n-k+1)!^2 \binom{2n}{n}}=0\; if\; k=0\; or= -1\; if\; k>0$$
which simplifies to
$$\sum_{n>0}\frac{(3n-2k+1)\binom{n}{k}^2}{(2n+1) \binom{2n}{n}}=2\; for\; all\; k>-1$$
Logically this looks like a physical impossibility. Would anyone believe that there is any way this could be true and if so how would one go about proving this paradox or seemingly impossibility.

Comment: I can see this question, if that helps.

Comment: yea it was a very long delay and some all the sudden message about inventing a new whatever you call it tags called binomial which seemed after i took that off then it posted

Comment: Now that the question has been posted, you should probably change the title to something that summarizes your specific question.

Comment: change the title where ? on meta ?

Comment: or maybe just delete it on meta if that were possible ?

Comment: though it is so ambiguous to know if one is on meta site or regular math site. I have never been able to determine that and as far as i know there is no way to determine whether one is on the meta or regular math site.

Comment: You posted this question on the regular math.stackexchange site, not on the meta site. I just edited the title to your question, and also removed the final sentence since your question was posted successfully. Feel free to make further edits if you'd like, however.